# Enviar formulario dinámico

Tags: javascript

Quería haceros una pregunta, a ver cómo puedo hacer esto:

Tengo una página donde tengo una serie de valores fijos y luego un div que contiene 5 text elements. Dicho div puede ser clonado, por lo que puedo tener el dive repetido varias veces pero con distintos valores.

Quiero pulsar el botón para ir a la siguiente página y pasarle todos los valores de todos los divs que se hayan clonado. El problema es que cuando se clonan todos los nombres son iguales y los id's tambien...es deecir, necesitaria poder cambiarle los nombres.

Esta es mi función:

```
function duplicar(id){

    var divclonado = $('#asegurado_'+id).clone();
    id++;
    var nombre='asegurado_' + id;
    id--;
    divclonado.attr("id",nombre);
    $('#asegurado_'+id).after(divclonado);
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura general del div que intentas clonar?
En qué momento se ejecuta la función duplicar y de dónde sale el id que espera recibir?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo dejar de usar var y empezar a usar let.

Te recomiendo también usar jQuery lo menos posible, porque 'contamina' el proceso de aprendizaje de Javascript puro. Además que ya es mucho más fácil que antes hacer cosas que solían hacerse sólo con jQuery.

```
function duplicar(id){
  const divOriginal = document.getElementById('asegurado_' + id);
  const divClonado = divOriginal.cloneNode(true); // true para copiar la estructura interna
  let newId = id + 1;
  // Si ya existe ese id, incrementarlo en 1
  while(document.getElementById('asegurado_' + newId)){
    newId++;
  }
  divClonado.id = 'asegurado_' + newId;
  divOriginal.parentElement.insertBefore(divClonado, divOriginal.nextElementSibling);
}
```

La parte en que se asigna el id no es la mejor en cuanto a rendimiento, pero no sé si se puedan clonar elementos de un id menor al máximo existente. Esto es, si existiendo el id asegurado_5, se puede clonar el asegurado_3, en cuyo caso, el ciclo asignaría asegurado_6. Si esto no fuera posible, en lugar del ciclo, te recomendaría encontrar último id con algo así:

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('[id^="asegurado_"]')].reverse()[0];
```